# Internet connections keep timing out

Tags: internet-connection, timeout

I've used Firefox for over 2 years without complaint. I'm running Windows 7 Ultimate, 32-bit.

Since a few days, certain sites won't load anymore, all giving a time-out. If I wait a few minutes, they do load, but after a few clicks, they don't work anymore, giving time-out again.

I've tried this on Firefox 3.6.10, IE8, IE9beta, Opera 10.62 and The latest Chrome dev. They all give the identical same problem. Cleared caches and cookies alike, nothing changes.

I've had MSE do a deep scan with the latest definition, no infection.

Search engines aren't affected, and most sites owned by Google, Yahoo, Microsoft or similar, have no problem loading, though I do see the time has increased a bit. I used to get Google in the blink of an eye, now it's a second or 3.

I've checked my connection speed, I can still get my usual maximum no problem.

I thought it might have been something I installed, but when at college, the wireless gives no problems at all. Everything loads like I'm used to. I've checked my router, and there are no reports of any attacks and all the settings look the same.

I'm out of ideas. Anybody got a diagnosis?

Comment: What websites are you trying to connect to?  Are they for sure still up?

Comment: @KronoS: yes, I've checked many with http://www.downforeveryoneorjustme.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Power down your router and modem for a few minutes, to get a new IP from your service provider.

Comment: Already done, no effect.

Comment: Check on your router for the DNS settings.  Then configure your network settings to use the IP addresses 8.8.8.8 and 8.8.4.4 as your DNS servers.